# React Native, Native Modules returns empty object - {}

Tags: react-native, native

I've written native module for React Native, everything was done according to official documentation, but something went wrong, and Native Modules returns only empty object.

**importing Native Modules in Component Home.js**

*All Module code was writen according to official docs*

```
import {
  NativeModules
} from 'react-native';

const { OptionsPackage } = NativeModules;

console.log(NativeModules) // {}
```

**MainApplication.java file**

```
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new OptionsPackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

**OptionsPackage.java file**

```
package package.name;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OptionsPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
            ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new OptionsModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

}
```

**OptionsModule.java**

```
package com.downloadmanager;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.InputStream;

... 
public class OptionsModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    ActivityManager activityManager;
    int currentSDK;
    ReactApplicationContext context;

    OptionsModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        this.activityManager = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ReactApplicationContext.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
        context = context;
        currentSDK = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "123";
    }

    private Map packageInfoToMap(PackageInfo pi) {
        PackageManager pm = this.context.getPackageManager();

        long longVersionCode;
        Map<String, Object> AppInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
            longVersionCode = pi.getLongVersionCode();
        } else
        {
            longVersionCode = pi.versionCode; }

        AppInfo.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
        AppInfo.put("versionName", pi.versionName);
        AppInfo.put("getLongVersionCode", longVersionCode);
        AppInfo.put("lastUpdateTime", (pi.lastUpdateTime));
        AppInfo.put("firstInstallTime", pi.firstInstallTime);

        String title = pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        String description =  pi.applicationInfo.loadDescription(pm).toString();
        Drawable icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);


        
        AppInfo.put("title", title);
        AppInfo.put("description", description);
        AppInfo.put("icon", icon);

        //get folder

        String apkDir = pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir;
        File file = new File(apkDir);
        double size = file.length();

        AppInfo.put("filePath", apkDir);
        AppInfo.put("size", size);

        return AppInfo;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public List listOfApps(String type) {
        List<PackageInfo> packages = this.context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        List<Map<String, Object>> listOfApps = new ArrayList();

        for (PackageInfo isPackage : packages) {
            boolean isSystem = (isPackage.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM;


            if(type == "systemOnly" && isSystem) {
                listOfApps.add(this.packageInfoToMap(isPackage));
            } else if (type == "nonSystem" && !isSystem) {
                listOfApps.add(this.packageInfoToMap(isPackage));
            } else {
                listOfApps.add(this.packageInfoToMap(isPackage));
            }
        }

        return listOfApps;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I am also facing a similar kind of issue did you solve this? If then please post the answer

Comment: Having a similar issue? did you find the answer?

Comment: Same issue - did anyone make any progress?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613550/react-native-nativemodules-not-importing-on-m1-silicon-mac-returning-empty-o

Answer (score 0):

Your getName() override method in OptionsModule is returning "123"

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "123";
}
```

This is how react native gets the name of your module that should show up on react native side.

Try changing it to "OptionsModule" and then in your Home.js do

```
const {OptionsModule} = NativeModules
```

Also try calling your @ReactMethod in js to see if it works, don't rely on console logging NativeModules.